# Building android sdk for tracking data in e-commerce apps

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I wanted to build an android SDK which can basically be used to track and collect product metrics. Some of the use cases are as below

1. Whenever user added any product into cart then we should be able to get data regarding product Id, no of items, price of product.
2. Whenever user makes an purchase we should get the same details as mentioned in above point.

The concern I am having is who will I write events/listeners that will be triggered whenever user add/purchase any product